# MySQL to JSON: Issue with encoding of German special characters in UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding, utf-8

I wrote a little script that takes the data from a MySQL table and puts it into a JSON array. However, there's an issue with character encoding, even though I have set UTF-8 everywhere. Here's the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JSON</title>
</head>

<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$con = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE");
if (!$con) {
    trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

mysql_query("SET NAMES SET 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[]=$r;
}

print json_encode($rows);


mysqli_close($con);

?>

</html>
```

In the output, I get the value "\u00e4" instead of "ä".

Some additional info:

- Table is in utf8_general_ci (as are all of its columns)
- PHP document is in UTF8

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: try [this](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me everything is working properly.  The reason why you see `\u00e4` instead of `ä` is because of the implementation of the JSON serializer.  What the serializer is doing is perfectly valid.

From the [JSON RFC Section 2.5 Strings](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
>   represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
>   by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
>   encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters A though
>   F can be upper or lowercase.  So, for example, a string containing
>   only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as
>   "\u005C".

The reason I suspect why this serializer escapes it for you is because [PHP doesn't natively support unicode](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a
>   byte. 
>   This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not 
>   offer native Unicode support.